# input and float label with pattern

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with an input tag and label its float . Everything works properly read , but when I insert a pattern in the input if this pattern is not satisfied with the effect float is not realized , and the text input overlaps with the label . I hope I was clear , sorry for my english.

this is css

```css
.card .input-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 60px 50px;
}
.card .input-container input {
  outline: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: 0;
  color: #212121;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.card .input-container input:focus ~ label {
  color: #9d9d9d;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
  transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
}
.card .input-container input:focus ~ .bar:before, .card .input-container input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}
.card .input-container input:valid ~ label {
  color: #9d9d9d;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
  transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
}
.card .input-container label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.card .input-container .bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #757575;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
.card .input-container .bar:before, .card .input-container .bar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #ed2553;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: .2s ease;
  transition: .2s ease;
}
.card .input-container .bar:before {
  left: 50%;
}
.card .input-container .bar:after {
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text" id="Username" required="required" pattern=".{3,}"  title="3 characters minimum" />
      <label for="Username">Username</label>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually looks good when I input something. What exactly is the issue? Can you kindly tell the steps to reproduce?

Comment: add less than 3 characters to the input then click outside the input to let the input lose focus is what i think the OP is talking about. Lets the label and value from the input overlap.

Comment: Okay, just found out that if you put `/` it overlaps, as it is not valid.

Comment: when the input is entered in the same less than 3 characters, then the pattern is not satisfied , the label overlaps with text input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you this, if you want to keep the animation intact. Checking the validity of the input, should be done using JavaScript and make the input, just be `required`. Remove the `pattern` altogether and give something like this:

```css
.card .input-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 60px 50px;
}
.card .input-container input {
  outline: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: 0;
  color: #212121;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.card .input-container input:focus ~ label {
  color: #9d9d9d;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
  transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
}
.card .input-container input:focus ~ .bar:before, .card .input-container input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}
.card .input-container input:valid ~ label {
  color: #9d9d9d;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
  transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
}
.card .input-container label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.card .input-container .bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #757575;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
.card .input-container .bar:before, .card .input-container .bar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #ed2553;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: .2s ease;
  transition: .2s ease;
}
.card .input-container .bar:before {
  left: 50%;
}
.card .input-container .bar:after {
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text" id="Username" required="required"  title="3 characters minimum" />
      <label for="Username">Username</label>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Or you can make the animation happen by adding a new class to the `input` using **JavaScript / jQuery**. A **pure CSS** solution for having both may not be possible. *I said may not, because, I cannot think of one. Let's see if someone else comes up with a solution.*

---

Alternate solution using jQuery:

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim().length > 0)
      $(this).addClass("non-empty");
    else
      $(this).removeClass("non-empty");
  });
});
```

```css
.card .input-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 60px 50px;
}
.card .input-container input {
  outline: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: 0;
  color: #212121;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.card .input-container input:focus ~ label {
  color: #9d9d9d;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
  transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
}
.card .input-container input:focus ~ .bar:before, .card .input-container input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}
.card .input-container input.non-empty ~ label {
  color: #9d9d9d;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
  transform: translate(-12%, -50%) scale(0.75);
}
.card .input-container label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.card .input-container .bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #757575;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
.card .input-container .bar:before, .card .input-container .bar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #ed2553;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: .2s ease;
  transition: .2s ease;
}
.card .input-container .bar:before {
  left: 50%;
}
.card .input-container .bar:after {
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text" id="Username" required="required" pattern=".{3,}"  title="3 characters minimum" />
      <label for="Username">Username</label>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```